# 100% width issue in CSS

Tags: html, css

I just purchased [this](http://themes.proteusnet.com/hairpress/) template. The template is cool working good in all browsers but when I load the template and then if I resize the browser there comes a horizontal scroll bar with white space. This is the only issue with the template. There is no one to give assistance regarding this issue. I believe I am good at CSS but as this template is having alls of lines I couldn't sort out where the issue is. I tried running Firebug to detect the issue but I couldn't. Can anyone help me by checking the CSS of this template using Firebug and suggest me the CSS code that will not show a horizontal scroll bar with white space.

Thanks.

Issue screenshot.

[image]

Comment: This is no freelancing site. Go to any freelancing site and post and ad and i am sure that your issue would get solved.

Comment: @NirmalRam - That's a wired answer. I am not asking you to build a website to hire a freelancer. I am asking to detect a bug which I couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

**Add this in your head section**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```